# Puppet - how do I verify the canonical location for modulepath on an agent?

Tags: puppet

I'm on an agent, and I want to know where the modulepath is.

I tried `puppet config print` but the values for `basemodulepath` and `modulepath` do not exist on the system.

I did a locate for some puppet files, and they are located at a directory that seems out of date. However, puppet should have run recently, and I verified with `/var/lib/puppet/state/last_run_summary.yaml`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you misunderstood the role of `puppet agent`. `Puppet agent` is designed to be a client of `puppet master`. Simplifying, it only role is to connect to `puppet master`, and apply received catalogue. Agent doesn't have `modulepath` because it is completely unnecessary for it. All modules are stored on `puppet master`.

Comment: How can I tell where modulepath is on the master? And how can I tell what box the master is located on?

Comment: Here you have an overview of puppet architecture: https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/4.2/reference/architecture.html, here is doc about conf files https://docs.puppetlabs.com/puppet/latest/reference/config_file_main.html , and here how to make a master-agent connection https://docs.puppetlabs.com/guides/install_puppet/post_install.html